pyo3_runtime. PanicException: called 'Result: :unwrap()
I got some error like that
sometimes it is work well but sometimes it gets that error
I tried try, except code but it doesnt work.

note: run with 'RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display a backtrace
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 54, in 
asyncio.run (start_buy (payer, valance, client))
File " /us/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/runners.py", line 43, in run
return loop.run_until_complete (main)
File "/us/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 566, in run_until_complete self.run_forever ()
File "/us/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events-py", line 534, in run_ forever self._run_once ()
File " /us/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1771, in _run_once
handle. _run ()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
File "main.py", line 20, in start_buy
buy_transaction=await buy (client, manny, payer, amount-0.02) #Enter amount of sol you wish to saand File "/workspace/contrader /buy_swap.py", line 80, in buy
E501 line too long (91 > 79 characters) | visual indent
txn = solana_client.send_transaction (swap_tx, payer, Wsol_account_keyPair)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/solana/rpc/api.py",line1067,insend_transaction
txn_resp = self.send_raw_transaction(txn.serialize() , opts=opts_to_use)
File "/us/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/solana/rpc/api.py",line992,insend_raw_transaction
resp = self._provider.make_request (body, SendTransactionResp)
File " /us/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/solana/exceptions.py", line 43, in argument_decorator return func (*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/solana/rpc/providers/http.py",line49,in make_request return _parse_raw(raw, parser=parser)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/solana/rpc/providers/core.py",line95,in_parse_raw
parsed = parser. from_json (raw) # type: ignore
pyo3_runtime. PanicException: called 'Result: :unwrap() on an 'Err' value: Error ("missing field 'data'", line: 0, column: 0)

I saw simillar question here here
but it is not work on me.
            instructions_swap = make_swap_instruction(amount_in,
                                                      WSOL_token_account,
                                                      swap_associated_token_address,
                                                      pool_keys,
                                                      mint,
                                                      solana_client,
                                                      payer,
                                                     True)
            params = CloseAccountParams(account=WSOL_token_account, dest=payer.pubkey(), owner=payer.pubkey(),
                                        program_id=TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID)
            closeAcc = (close_account(params))
            if swap_token_account_Instructions != None:
                swap_tx.add(swap_token_account_Instructions)

            #compute unit price and comute unit limit gauge your gas fees more explanations on how to calculate in a future article
            
            
            swap_tx.add(instructions_swap,set_compute_unit_price(25_232),set_compute_unit_limit(2000337),closeAcc)
            print(swap_tx, payer, Wsol_account_keyPair)
            txn = solana_client.send_transaction(swap_tx, payer,Wsol_account_keyPair)

error started here and in make_swap_instruction
keys = [
        AccountMeta(pubkey=TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["amm_id"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["authority"], is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["open_orders"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["target_orders"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["base_vault"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["quote_vault"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=SERUM_PROGRAM_ID, is_signer=False, is_writable=False), 
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["market_id"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["bids"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["asks"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["event_queue"], is_signer=False, is_writable=Ture),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["market_base_vault"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["market_quote_vault"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["market_authority"], is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=token_account_in, is_signer=False, is_writable=True),  #UserSourceTokenAccount 
        AccountMeta(pubkey=token_account_out, is_signer=False, is_writable=True), #UserDestTokenAccount 
        AccountMeta(pubkey=owner.pubkey(), is_signer=True, is_writable=False) #UserOwner 
    ]

    data = SWAP_LAYOUT.build(       
        dict(
            instruction=9,
            amount_in=int(amount_in),
            min_amount_out=calculate_min_amount_out(amount_in, 0.05, buy)
        )
    )
    return Instruction(AMM_PROGRAM_ID, data, keys)

What can I do for fix it?
